# Unix wget automation in Python fails during second call

Tags: python, wget

I'm trying to automate a process by which a bitstream is intercepted using wget at a specified IP and port.  Previously, in order to do this, I would run

```
$ wget "http://<IP>:<Port>/audio_tap?tap=codecout" -O <filename>
```

which consistently worked fine. Then I automated the entire process using Python, in this case, working my way through a set queue of files to download which would be downloaded in turn from the same IP and port.

Upon automating the process in Python, in order to maintain timings, this process was executed in a subprocess with subprocess.Popen while other actions controlled the bitstream heading towards that IP and port.

After making a loop to pull multiple files in, ending the subprocess after each iteration and restarting it at the beginning, everything worked perfectly except that the bitstream would be saved for a few hundred KB before failing entirely.  This issue persisted for each following download after the second.

The code is roughly as follows:

```
def foo(arg):
    def startstream(____):
        stream.start()
        time.sleep(length)
        stream.end()

    sim = multiprocessing.Process(target=startstream, name='sim', args=(____))
    sim.start()

    wgetargs = 'wget "http://%s:1400/audio_tap?tap=codecout" -O "%s"'%(IP,filename)
    SubCapture = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(wgetargs), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    SubCapturePID = SubCapture.pid

    while sim.is_alive():
          pass
    os.system('kill %d' %(SubCapturePID))


for i in aList:
    foo(i)
```

Finally, the error is some combination of these:
    beginning stream

```
--Date Time--  http://<IP>:<Port>/audio_tap?tap=codecout
Connecting to <IP>:<Port>... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified
Saving to: ‘filename_0’

file_0               [                <=> ]  12.82M   172KB/s               


beginning stream

--Date Time--  http://<IP>:<Port>/audio_tap?tap=codecout
Connecting to <IP>:<Port>... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified
Saving to: ‘filename_1’

file_1     [          <=>       ] 278.75K  --.-KB/s               


beginning stream

--Date Time--  http://<IP>:<Port>/audio_tap?tap=codecout
Connecting to <IP>:<Port>... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ending
```

Thanks for any help you can give, or any insight.

MacOS 10.12.5
Python 2.7.13
GNU wget 1.19.1 built on darwin 16.4.0

Comment: Could you show us your python code, please? Or at least, enough of it to reproduce the error

Comment: I think we'll need more context. Please show how you're using `subprocess` (code snippets), and how you're closing it. Also, if you want fine control over http you might be better off using a library like `requests` instead of an external process.

Comment: Both a summary of the code and the error to stdout are in the most recent edit.  Thanks.

Comment: @z0r if you don't mind, how would I use `requests` or something similar to download an incoming bitstream rather than just a file with an extension hosted on the web.  This file has no type yet and is considered raw data.

Comment: I'm no `requests` expert, but you probably want to open a request with [`stream=True`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) and then [iterate over the contents](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) and write it to a file. Use `with` statements for both the request and the file to ensure they get closed properly.